# Change Hashtable into an array of Linked lists

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list, nodes, hashtable

I have created a hash table class in my program. However I would like to change it to be an array of linked lists. I am not familiar with linked lists because they are very confusing to me. Would anyone be able to explain how to change an algorithm into an new format? Below is the hashtable I created. Any help is appreciated. Thank you! :)

```
public class hashtable
    {

        //inner class hash entry to be added to hash table
        class hashentry
        {
            int key;
            string data;

            //setters and getters
            public hashentry(int key, string data)
            {
                this.key = key;
                this.data = data;
            }
            public int getkey()
            {
                return key;
            }
            public string getdata()
            {
                return data;
            }
        }


        int maxSize; // table length
        hashentry[] table; //create array of hash entries

        /*
        *
        *Hash table constructor given size paramter to set the length of the array

        *set table to null
        */

        public hashtable(int size)
        {
            maxSize = size;
            table = new hashentry[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                table[i] = null;
            }
        }

        /*
        * using key, get element at given key parameter, return key to string
        */
        public string retrieve(int key)
        {
            int hash = key % maxSize;
            while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getkey() != key)
            {
                hash = (hash + 1) % maxSize;
            }
            if (table[hash] == null)
            {
                return "nothing found!";
            }
            else
            {
                return table[hash].getdata();
            }
        }

        /*
        * using string data, get element at given string if it is exact, return hash entry to console
        */
        public void retrievedata(string data)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= table.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (table[i].getdata().Equals(data) && table[i].getdata() != null && table != null && i <= maxSize)//if we have null entries
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Key value :{0} , Data Value :{1}, Length of Data : {2}", table[i].getkey(), table[i].getdata(), table[i].getdata().Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        /*
        * checks for open spaces in the table for insertion method
        */

        private bool checkOpenSpace()//checks for open spaces in the table for insertion
        {
            bool isOpen = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
            {
                if (table[i] == null)
                {
                    isOpen = true;
                }
            }
            return isOpen;
        }


        /*
        * Method to print all elements of the hash array
        * Print all iterates over all the n elements in the container, so it is o(n) operation.
        */

        public void print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
            {
                if (table[i] == null && i <= maxSize)//if we have null entries
                {
                    continue;//dont print them, continue looping
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key value :{0} , Data Value :{1}, Length of Data : {2}", table[i].getkey(), table[i].getdata(), table[i].getdata().Length);
                }
            }
        }

        /*
        *Quadratic probe insert is in best case o(1) when location of the hash is empty and in worst
        * case o(n) when it is not empty, so you must loop until you find one that is.
        * if quadratic probe insert is not necessary, it needs to change the pointer to the hash so it is o(1)
        */

        public void quadraticHashInsert(int key, string data)
        {
            // quadratic probing method
            if (!checkOpenSpace())//if no open spaces available
            {
                Console.WriteLine("table is at full capacity!");
                return;
            }

            int j = 0;
            int hash = hash1(key);
            if (hash >= 0)
            {
                while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getkey() != key && hash >= 0)
                {
                    j++;
                    hash = (hash + j * j) % maxSize;

                    // hash = (hash + j * j) % maxSize;
                }

                if (table[hash] == null)
                {
                    table[hash] = new hashentry(key, data);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
        private int hash1(int key)
        {
            return key % maxSize;
        }
        private int hash2(int key)
        {
            //must be non-zero, less than array size, ideally odd
            return 5 - key % 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason your not using a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` ? Also how do you envisage the conversion from a Hashtable to an array of linked lists? there is a fair bit of missing information here

Comment: @TheGeneral I intend on implementing a search and insertion method into the class. The algorithm will add to the linkedlist, and search will to the index and does a linear search. I'm not sure what ```Dictionary<TKey,TValue>``` is.

Comment: If you are familiar with implementation of linked list itself - it's just a node which points to another node and so on.

So I guess you just have to add a field to your hashentry:
hashentry next;

And here you go - you have an array of linked lists (that's actually how hashmap is implemented in Java)